# Constructing hashes of hash and then printing

Tags: perl

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;
use Sys::Hostname;

use strict;
use Time::Local;
use warnings;

my %resultMap=();
my @myarray = (
'a',
'b',
'c',
'd'
);

my %ha = (
            A => {'UserNum' => 1, 'Password' => 'abc', 'Server' => 'AAAA',  'Database' => 'BBB'},
            B => {'UserNum' => 2, 'Password' => 'abc', 'Server' => 'AAAA',  'Database' => 'BBB'}                                    
          );    

for my $region ( keys %ha ) {

    my %hashone=();  
    foreach (@myarray) {    
        my $myStr =  $_ ;   
        $hashone {$myStr} = $ha{'UserNum'};

        print "$myStr ---> $hashone{$myStr}\n";
    }

    $resultMap{$region} = { %hashone }; 

}

for my $regionKey (keys %resultMap ){
    print "Key -$regionKey\n";      
    for my $table ( keys %{ $resultMap{$regionKey} } ) {
        my %counthash = $resultMap{$regionKey};
         print "$regionKey : $counthash{$table}\n";
    }
}
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong here.I am expecting numbers in output while it is printing following error.

```
    Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) at testHash.pl line 29.
    a --->
    Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) at testHash.pl line 29.
    b --->
    Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) at testHash.pl line 29.
    c --->
    Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) at testHash.pl line 29.
    d --->
    Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) at testHash.pl line 29.
    a --->
    Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) at testHash.pl line 29.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a deeper level nested structure than you think. I've marked the lines with `# <-- here` where I've made changes. The second change (on line 39) is because `$resultMap{$regionKey}` itself contains a hash, so to copy it, you need to dereference it by surrounding it with the hash's circumfix operator (`%{}`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;
use Sys::Hostname;

use strict;
use Time::Local;
use warnings;

my %resultMap=();
my @myarray = (
'a',
'b',
'c',
'd'
);

my %ha = (

            A => {'UserNum' => 1, 'Password' => 'abc', 'Server' => 'AAAA',  'Database' => 'BBB'},
            B => {'UserNum' => 2, 'Password' => 'abc', 'Server' => 'AAAA',  'Database' => 'BBB'}
          );

for my $region ( keys %ha ) {

    my %hashone=();
    foreach (@myarray) {
        my $myStr =  $_ ;
        $hashone{$myStr} = $ha{$region}->{'UserNum'}; # <-- here

        print "$myStr ---> $hashone{$myStr}\n";
    }

    $resultMap{$region} = { %hashone };

}

for my $regionKey (keys %resultMap ){
    print "Key -$regionKey\n";
    for my $table ( keys %{ $resultMap{$regionKey} } ) {
        my %counthash = %{$resultMap{$regionKey}};  # <-- here
         print "$regionKey : $counthash{$table}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `Data::Dumper` is invaluable for figuring these types of things out. `print Dumper \%ha;` for example.